# jQuery Parallax Scroll disable on mobile/tablet

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I am using a free template to build a static website (http://keenthemes.com/preview/megakit/) but I cannot seem to disable `parllax` scroll on mobile.

I have been trying to modify `parallax.min.js` file but cannot get it work on mobile devices. Images are not displayed on mobile at all.

Below is the code:

```
var Parallax=function(){"use strict";var a=function(){$(".js__parallax-window").parallax("50%",.1)};return{init:function(){a()}}}();$(document).ready(function(){if(window.innerWidth>760){Parallax.init()}});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have seen your website images are displaying in mobiles mode. I think the cashing problem is there once you press control+f5 keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media(max-width: 480px){
    .js__parallax-window {
        background-attachment: unset !important;
    }
}
```

Use this code in your css file, this will help for sure

Comment: Is is also possible to make sure that the image is not distorted when mobile is rotated?

Comment: what do you mean by image distorted here? I am not getting it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. For example,  one of the image is only showing half if the actual image when phone is rotated

Comment: oh,, tell me the exact image in your design on website, will try to fix it if I can and will give you the code.

Comment: thanks for this. will provide it to you once the site is ready :)